# Showing data from another table if it exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a hard time trying to get the correct data out of my DB.

I have a couple of tables:

```
events_template          laser_events
| id | something |       | id  | extid |   added   |
==================       ===========================
|  1 | something |       |  1  |   7   |   added   |
|  2 | something |       |  2  |   4   |   added   |
|  3 | something |       |  3  |   2   |   added   |
|  4 | something |       |  4  |   1   |   added   |
|  5 | something |       |  5  |   9   |   added   |
|  6 | something |       |  6  |   3   |   added   |
|  7 | something |
|  8 | something |
|  9 | something |
| 10 | something |
| 11 | something |
| 12 | something |
| 13 | something |
| 14 | something |
```

What I am trying to do is get some output that will show me the results of both tables together linked by id and extid, but still show the results from events_template even if there isn't a matching laser_events row.

I've tried something like

```
SELECT 
     id,  
     extid 
FROM 
     events_template, 
     laser_events 
WHERE 
     events_template.id = laser_events.ext_id;
```

But that doesn't show me the events_template rows if there isn't a matching laser_events row.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't use the syntax `table1, table2 WHERE blahblahblah`.  That syntax was replaced by the ANSI-92 syntax for `INNER JOIN` and *(for your needs)* `LEFT JOIN`, etc.  The older syntax is more than 20 years outdated, harder to read, more prone to mistakes, and on some systems doesn't actually work as intended in all cases *(and so is deprecated on those systems)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.id, l.ext_id 
FROM events_template e
LEFT JOIN laser_events  l ON e.id = l.ext_id;
```

Comment: That's great man. one other thing to it that I thought would be trivial but isn't working as I am expecting. I also want to only show results where a timestamp in events_template is greater than 2016-05-25 07:30:00, if I add "WHERE e.timestamp > '2016-05-25 07:30:00' to the end it again only shows the matching rows as before.

Comment: @Steve This should return all records from `events_template` table for which `timestamp > '2016-05-25 07:30:00'` *irrespective* of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: You're right, I was doing it on l.timestamp by mistake (the tables I made aren't real so got the names mixed up :P) Thanks!